# Timer makes UI unresponsive?

Tags: multithreading, performance, qt, timer, signals

I use a timer to emit a signal and call a slot function which updates the UI according to new data.

I've calculated the time to run that function as being quite short. When the timer is set to 1000ms, the UI responds quite slow.

I tried to move that functionality to a thread but I'm finding it difficult since a lot of the functionality needs to access the UI class's protected values.

I'm going to try moving the timer to another thread and leave the update functionality in the UI class (main window) but I don't know if it will help.

Why is the timer causing the UI to be slow and unresponsive? Will a thread be lighter and consume less CPU time? How can I fix this?

```
    initTimer()
    {
        refreshTimer = new QTimer(this);
        connect(refreshTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(refreshDisplay));
        refreshTimer->start(1000);
    }
```

refresh slot function called every 1000ms:

```
    void refreshDisplay()
    {
        ui->tableWidget->setUpdatesEnabled(false);

        for(int queue_i = size_1, index = 0; queue_i >= 0; queue_i--, index++)
        {
            LogInfoItem* logItem = (LogInfoItem*)logDisplayQueue.at(queue_i);

            QString BITS_str = bits2Hexs(logItem->BITS);


            ui->tableWidget->item(index, 0)->setText(logItem->time);//time
            ui->tableWidget->item(index, 1)->setText(logItem->name);//name
            ui->tableWidget->item(index, 2)->setText(BITS_str);//BITS

            if(queue_i == oldRowItemNo)ui->tableWidget->selectRow(index);
        }

        ui->tableWidget->setUpdatesEnabled(true);

        Q_FOREACH(Page* p, PageInfoList)
        {
            p->refresh();
        }

        Q_FOREACH(IconLabel* icl, iconLabelList)
        {
            icl->refresh();
        }
    }
```

What 'refresh()' does is just changing icons and texts in the ui according to the data inside.   Besides, i've made the data static, but still cannot fix it.
    (I've tested the function, almost no time consuming...)

Comment: Can you post some code or write sample code which can repro your problem? My guess is that there is slow logic in UI update which is triggered by timer, causing timer to re-trigger again, creating a queue of events.

Comment: Is the UI slow after awhile or immediately? Try removing all of the UI update code in `refreshDisplay()` and replace it with maybe updating a label displaying a counter. This should tell you if the UI update code it causing the lag or if the problem is elsewhere like some other routine eating up the CPU.

Comment: A thread won't help, and as you mentioned you can't update GUI stuff from a thread anyway.

Comment: @Rubby: I think we still don't have enough info to help you. As @Arnold pointed out, if `refreshDisplay()` is truly as fast as you claim, then your timer may not be the problem. Try commenting out the entire contents of the slot and slowly uncommenting until things get slow again to narrow it down. Before you reach for a solution (like multithreading), make sure you've found the actual problem. :)

Comment: Thank you, I have  used your mehods and finally  find  the cpu eater,  it is setIcon function . I add an if  statement before it,  and  wll not  call it if  data  not  changed. Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, I have used your mehods and finally find the cpu eater, it is setIcon function . I add an if statement before it, and wll not call it if data not changed. Thank you, everyone!